# Error in Spring+Hibernate+Maven project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, intellij-idea

I've a problem in my project, nothing help..
Other classes will not show, because everything is good, how to fix this error? I write in the Intellij IDEA, create maven project, load spring and hibernate libraries, also load mysql connector and other libraries.
My main class:

```
import DAO.StoreDAO;
import logic.Store;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args){
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            new String[] { "applicationContext.xml" }, true);
    StoreDAO studDao = (StoreDAO) context.getBean("dataDao");
    Store data1 = new Store();
    data1.setName("test1");
    data1.setType("test1Type");
    data1.setAddress("test1Address");
    studDao.saveStore(data1);
    System.out.println(studDao.findStore("t%").size());
}
}
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
                   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
                   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
                   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="logic" />

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="myPointcut"
                  expression="execution(* DAO.*.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="myPointcut" />
</aop:config>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="get*" propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="find*" propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="save*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/practick</value>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>root</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value></value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataDao" class="DAO.Impl.StoreHibernateDAO">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

Error list:

```
19, 2014 7:07:22 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext         prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1e0aca6:     startup date [Fri Dec 19 19:07:22 EET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
груд. 19, 2014 7:07:22 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader     loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
груд. 19, 2014 7:07:23 PM org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource     setDriverClassName
INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
груд. 19, 2014 7:07:23 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: Hibernate 3.0.1
груд. 19, 2014 7:07:23 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: hibernate.properties not found
груд. 19, 2014 7:07:23 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: using CGLIB reflection optimizer
груд. 19, 2014 7:07:23 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
груд. 19, 2014 7:07:23 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: configuring from url:     file:/C:/Users/Oleg%20Svyryd/IdeaProjects/untitled/target/classes/hibernate.cfg.xml
груд. 19, 2014 7:07:23 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'txAdvice':     Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionManager' while setting bean property     'transactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:     Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource     [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean     property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name     'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method     failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is     required to use <mapping clazz="logic.Store"/>
at     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)...
at Main.main(Main.java:10)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
... 30 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name    'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve    reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name   'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method   failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is   required to use <mapping clazz="logic.Store"/>
... 30 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use     <mapping clazz="logic.Store"/>
```

And many other...

Comment: This is way too much for anyone to dig through. Please edit this down to just the code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I left only the main class code, a list of errors and pom.xml file.

Comment: Error on line:  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            new String[] { "applicationContext.xml" }, true);

Comment: please post application context, remove pom

Comment: posted applicationContext)

Comment: The error is clearly caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use     <mapping clazz="logic.Store"/

Comment: but class is exist, and the path to class is correct in hibernate.cfg.xml: <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <mapping class="logic.Store"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>

Comment: Could it be that the project uses JPA-annotated entities and yet configures hibernate session factory? If yes, is there a reason for not using EntityManagerFactory/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean instead?

Comment: @badCoder - surely class exist, you would get another error when the class would not be available.

Comment: How do I know that the project uses JPA-annotated entities and yet configures hibernate session factory?

Comment: The project does use hibernate session factory due to bean with id="sessionFactory" and of class LocalSessionFactoryBean. The logic.Story would be an JPA entity if it was annotated with  @javax.persistence.Entity. Whereas this is set-up which I have seen running several times I never understood the motivation for it.

Comment: You might try with http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/annotation/AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.html instead of LocalSessionFactoryBEan.

Comment: Did it help? I  might register an answer if it did, letting the community to profit from known solution for given problem.

Comment: @Michal, me help this solve: http://www.journaldev.com/3524/spring-hibernate-integration-example-tutorial-spring-4-hibernate-3-and-hibernate-4

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure a few things

```
<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/practick</value>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>root</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value></value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

1. Make sure you have entered password
2. Change jdbc:mysql://localhost/practick to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/practick
3. Make sure that you have an existing database by name 'practick'.

This error is basically arising from the datasource or SessionFactory and it gets chained to the first resource bean.

txAdvice requires transaction manager which requires sessionFactory

Your error is actualy this point where is shows

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
```

ADD the following and check if it works

Spring does support auto scanning of entity classes through:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="your.package.name" />
```

Comment: I changed what you wrote in url, add <context:component-scan base-package="your.package.name" /> in applicationContext.xml, not work, same error